Maven dependency exclusions not working as expected
I have the following situation:

3 libraries: library A, library B and library A-updated (that's the name)
my main project which has the following dependencies in pom: A-updated and B
B has A as dependency in its pom

Since A-updated and A are essentially the same library, but with different artifactId, I will get NoSuchField/Method errors because my project might reference the version from A, instead of A-updated.
I tried the following configuration in my main project's pom, but without any luck:
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>B</artifactId>
            <version>1.00.01.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.test/groupId>
                    <artifactId>A</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

When running mvn:dependency tree I can still see the A library there. Do you have any thoughts?

Hold on, I am slightly confused, you are trying to exclude A from module B, but A-updated in part of module A? Please redefine question with A, B, and C modules to understand question correctly.

If you can still see the A lib it's likely being used as transitived dependency by another dependency... ?
